# Not able to use H264 (video/avc) Encoder on Intel x86 device, Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, x86, intel, android-mediacodec

I intend to encode raw YUV Data to H264 data for which I'm using Android's MediaCodec interface. Below is the snippet I have in place for the same:

```
MediaCodec mEncoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");

MediaFormat mVideoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640 , 480);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64000);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 24);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE, MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AVCProfileBaseline);

mEncoder.configure(mVideoFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mEncoder.start();
ByteBuffer[] mInputVideoBuffers = mEncoder.getInputBuffers();
ByteBuffer[] mOutputVideoBuffers = mEncoder.getOutputBuffers();
```

Although **it works well on ARM devices**, it fails on Intel x86 device I have (Samsung Tab 3) with below message:

> E/ACodec(21756): [OMX.Intel.VideoEncoder.AVC] ERROR(0x80001001)
>
> E/MediaCodec(21756): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001,
>   internalError -2147483648)

Any help on this would be useful.

Comment: The error reported is `OMX_ErrorUndefined` i.e. `0x80001001`. This is a very generic error which can be reported by the underlying component and hence, doesn't really help to identify the root cause of the error. If you can enable logs in `ACodec` module, it might be more useful to debug the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the fix for the issue. **I did not release the Codec before creating another one**. Multiple instances of Encoder is not permissible on Samsung Tab 3 running on Intel x86 device. This behaviour is pretty inconsistent across android devices; taking into account other devices on which I've had tested my code.

Answer (score 0):

The code shown won't work on some ARM devices.  `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar` isn't supported everywhere.

You need to detect the set of available color formats at runtime.  See the `isRecognizedFormat()` method in [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest).  To pass CTS, the device must allow one of those formats.  There's five listed, but really there's only two (planar and semi-planar), and they're not radically different.

Comment: Hi, I do query for appropriate color_format supported by the device running my code. The snippet shown in the question is only meant for a particular device, which supports COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar and hence the forced color_format.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details then.  What call is executing when it fails?  Is there anything else "interesting" in logcat above the errors?  The error codes from MediaCodec aren't very useful.

Comment: Found the fix for the issue. Have added as the answer to my question. Looking at the detailed (system-scope) logcat did help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Intel Devices Encoder.getOutput is Crashing , Created a media format and directly supplied to the encoder

```
MediaFormat mVideoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 640 , 480);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64000);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 24);
mVideoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
```

mTrackIndex = mMuxer.addTrack(mVideoFormat );